# Circular buffer of an array?

Tags: c++, boost, circular-buffer

I have a two dimensional double I need to keep in a circular buffer.  I'd prefer to keep it together in one buffer instead of having to keep up with two single dimensional buffers.  Is it possible to do this easily, or would it be best to go ahead and just use two buffers?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean a little bit? Do you mean a two-dimensional array of doubles? And what do you mean when you say you need to keep it in a circular buffer?

Comment: Hard to say exactly what you're looking for, but with simple arithmetic it's possible to treat a 1D array as a 2D array. Simply do `arr[ y * width + x ]` to get the element at the xy position.

Comment: @David - Yes, a 2d arrray like 'double myDouble[1];' I need to store in a circular buffer.

Comment: @Dave I haven't tried anything really, I was looking over the documentation for boost::circular_buffer, and wondering if I could do this or had to use two buffers.

Comment: @Ylisar This may be something I'll look into, but it does complicate the buffer access a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of each element is going to be the same, i.e. D1 x D2, you can just allocate an array

```
double data[D1*D2*numElem]
```

and use row/column major indexing ( i*D2 + j or i*D1 + j) to access values within each element. Of course whenever you resize or insert/delete an element a new buffer will have to be allocated and values copied. If the size of each element is variable or you think insertion/deletion/resize are going to be common use two buffers. If the container is stable and iteration over elements common a single buffer may be better.

Comment: Not too sure about this.  Having to recreate the buffer each time you add to it or remove it is  a bit of a waste of resources, is it not?  My main reason for wanting to use a single 2d array in one buffer over two separate buffers is the possibility of the second buffer being updated between reads and the data getting "out of sync".

Comment: @Johnny is your goal to have a circular buffer with 2d array elements? If so, instantiating boost::circular_buffer with double[] then row/column major indexing would be the most straightforward. Or do you want a 2d object whose rows/columns each have circular buffer functionality?

Comment: My goal is (or rather, was) to have one circular buffer of 2d array elements (one array of double[2]), kept in one buffer.  I say 'was' because looking further into boost, I think it's a bit too complicated for my skill level at the moment, and it may be a bit of overkill for my purpose.  I am now writing my own linear buffer class tailored to my purpose.  I think all I have left is the resizing functions and I'll be done.  Hopefully today or tomorrow. I'll post my class here on Stack Overflow for comments/suggestions when I get it working.  This has actually been quite fun.